# __attribute__ on function pointers

Tags: c, clang

Sometimes I write wrappers around printf-style functions for a variety of reasons, and I really like having clang tell me about type mismatches between format specifiers and actual arguments. Consider:

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2))) void log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
}

int main(void)
{
    log("%s", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

If compiled with `-Wall`, it neatly informs me about that type mistake:

```
test.c:14:15: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    log("%s", 42);
         ~~   ^~
         %d
```

That works very well for functions, but when it comes to function *pointers*, `__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)))` seems to have no effect anymore. The following code:

```c
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*log_t)(const char*, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

static __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2))) void log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
}

int main(void)
{
    log_t func = &log;
    (*func)("%s", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

compiles without warnings under `-Wall`, but the resulting program segfaults. I tried putting the attribute specifier in every part of the typedef, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Is there a way with clang to specify attributes (or *this* attribute) for function pointers so that it is actually picked up during compilation?
If it matters, my clang reports its version as: `Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the attribute specifier on the line with the pointer declaration works (i.e. results in a warning about mismatched arguments)

```
log_t func __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2))) = log;
```

So I think you're stuck with using a macro if the goal is to minimize typing and keep the code clean. Something like this:

```
#define checkargs __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)))

typedef void (*log_t)(const char*, ...);

static checkargs void log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, va);
    va_end(va);
}

int main(void)
{
    log_t checkargs func = log;
    func("%s", 42);
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, changing the call to `(*func)("%s", 42);` seems to break this... nevertheless a solution I can work with. :)

Comment: @Siguza Hmm, strange. But as long as it works for you, that's all that matters :)

Comment: If you're using a macro, why not `static checkargs void log(...) { ... }`?

Comment: @Siguza: It's probably because the attribute is attached to either the declaration of the pointer variable or to the type of the pointer variable but not to the type of the pointed-to value. When you indirect through the pointer, you're looking past any attributes that were attached to the pointer variable's declaration or type. You would need to attach the attribute to the pointed-to type (which is a function type), but GCC gives us no way to do that unfortunately.

Comment: @MattWhitlock but if `func` is a function pointer, shouldn't `func(...)` and `(*func)(...)` be equivalent?

Comment: @Siguza: They're functionally equivalent but not syntactically equivalent. Because the attribute attaches to the pointer and not to the pointed-to function type, you have to call the function through the pointer (which has attributed type *pointer-to-function*), not through the pointed-to address value (which has non-attributed type *function*). Low-level language syntax detail that ordinarily doesn't matter but does when we're talking about compiler internals.